# Hide objects in storyboard?

Tags: xcode, storyboard

I have some UIviews with several Pickers. These pickers is shown when needed. I would like to hide them in Storyboard so I can work with the underlying view without having to move them around each time. Possible?

Comment: One more reason why I avoid the Interface Builder.

Answer (score 4):

Mark the view as not installed

[image]

The compiler will throw warnings but thats helpful in this case.

A cool shortcut is to CMD-CTRL-SHIFT click the element which will give you a selectable list of the hierarchy at that point

[image]